# Color coded background of a 2d Plot and a density plot

Tags: plotting

I want to create this graph:

[image]

Assume I have this 2d plot:

```
Plot[Exp[-(x - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I want to color the background according to the value of the x axis. So that I get the plot shown above. Now assume I have a matrix which its entries are within the limits of the x axis of my 2d plot.

Matrix distribution:

```
dis = Table[10*N@Exp[-(x - 5)^2 - (y - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];
MatrixPlot[dis]
```

[image]

How can I use the same color code as the 2d plot in the density plot of `dis`? Each entry of `dis`is within the limits of the x-axis of the 2d plot. I want to color these entries according to the color code used in the 2d plot.

Comment: post your matrix please

Answer (score 4):

Using [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) and [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

```
c1 = 3.742*10^8;
c2 = 1.4388*10^4;
ee[x_, v_] := c1/((x^5 Exp[(c2/(x v))] - 1));
Plot[ee[x, 5500], {x, 0.2, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][x]], 
 Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {0.2, 0}]
```

[image]

Update (Based on question change)

```
Show[Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction ->  Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][x]],
  Filling -> Axis],
 Plot[Exp[-(x - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[RegionPlot[x > 0 && y > 0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][(x/2) + (y/2)]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True], 
 ContourPlot[Exp[-(x - 5)^2 - (y - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  Contours -> Join[Range[0, 1, 0.1]], ContourShading -> None, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: little addition to fill whole background,  Show[{Plot[Exp[-(x - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}],
  Plot[2, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}][x]], 
   Filling -> Axis], 
  Plot[Exp[-(x - 5)^2], {x, 0, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]}]

Comment: In the density plot shouldn't the value decreases as we move away from x = 5 and y = 5?

Comment: @MOON it does if you hover over the contours it shows that ... I though you wanted the same color background as the 2D plot

Comment: @Young I do not want the same color background. I want to color the entries of `dis` with the same color code as the 2d plot.

Comment: @MOON I don't think that's possible since in the 2d graph the same y value is associated with more than one color. I updated the second plot to something close

Comment: @Young. In the 2d plot you associated each value in the x axis to a specific color. Now the values in the x axis makes a matrix which I called `dis`. If each entry of this matrix `dis` is colored the same as before like you did in the 2d plot I get what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data comes as a list of pairs `{{x,y},...}`, I'd use `Show` with a contour plot like this:

```
dat = Table[{i, Exp[-i^2]*(1 + RandomReal[])}, {i, -5, 5, 0.2}];
combinedPlot[dat_]:=Show[
  ListContourPlot[
   Flatten[Table[{i, j, i}, {j, Last/@dat}, {i, First/@dat}], 1]
   , ContourStyle -> None
   , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #] &)
   , Contours -> 100
   , PlotRangePadding -> None
   ],
 ListPlot[
  dat
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotRange -> All
  , PlotStyle -> Black
  ]
 ];

combinedPlot[dat]
```

Gives:

[image]

You can extend this function to take options for the two plots if you like, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

## workInProgress...

```
lines = Table[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}, {x, -2, 2, 0.01}];
```

>

```
Show[
   Graphics[{Hue[LogisticSigmoid[#[[1, 1]]]], Line[#]}] & /@ lines,  

   Plot[E^-x^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Black],

   AspectRatio -> 1

]
```

[image]